# Unable to migrate android sqllite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have been running the onUpgrade method without issues, until this column:

```
    @OnUpgrade
    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {        
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE parents ADD COLUMN account_is_in_credit_for_amount TEXT DEFAULT ''");
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

I have updated the database version. The above has been simplified to try and make sure that nothing else is causing this column to not be created.

Note that if I uninstall the app and reinstall the app, then it runs without issue.

How would I go about debugging this issue further?

I imagine I need to provide more information, but I'm not sure what would help. Every idea that I have had, I have tried.

The error is:

```
unable to resume activity
{... .SplashScreenActivity}
android.database.sqlite.SQLLiteException: no such columns: parents.account_is_in_credit_for_amount (code 1):, while selecting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction():

> The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without
>   being marked as clean (by calling setTransactionSuccessful). Otherwise
>   they will be committed.

So call:

```
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
```

before:

```
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm convinced that I have made table updates before without this line. Any ideas why it might have worked before and not for this one?

Comment: According to the documentation all transactions are rolled back without it. So I can't tell.

Comment: Maybe you did not use transactions at all when you made the updates but simply executed the statements?

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised, that I did have that line in there... I just missed it...

Comment: I'm sure that you will never miss it again.

Comment: Haha, yes, me too! Thanks again